# Why does Firestore Cloud Function return a bad request response?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I'm following the tutorial on firebase's youtube channel on [using custom claims for authorization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs).  While attempting to call a cloud function, I continually receive a 'bad request: Invalid argument' response from the firebase server.  The function never even gets called.  I'm guessing the `data` structure in incorrect (invalid argument), but not sure why.  Can someone explain this?

cloud function:

```
exports.addAdmin = functions.https.onCall( (data: any, context: any) => {
  const email = data.email;
  return grantAdminRole(email).then(() => {
    return{
      result: 'Admin role has been assigned successfully'
    }
  }).catch( err => {
    return{
      error: err
    }
  })
})

async function grantAdminRole(email: string): Promise<void> {
  const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);
  if( user.customClaims && user.customClaims.admin === true ) {
    return;
  } else {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
      admin: true
    })
  }
};
```

client:

```
endpoint = 'https://[MY_FUNCTION_URL]';
userEmail = 'test@test.com';

constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {}

grantAdminRole() {
  this.http.post(this.endpoint, this.userEmail ).subscribe( res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server-side implements a [**callable** Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) as shown by:

```
functions.https.onCall
```

But your client then tries to invoke it as a [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) with:

```
this.http.post(this.endpoint, ...
```

While callable functions are built on top of HTTP functions, they cannot be invoked in the same way. You should either [use the client-side functions SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) to call the callable Cloud Function, or [implement the wire protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).